# how to get json data in suggestion using type-ahead in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, typeahead

I am new in `angular.js`, I am creating a suggestion box for my form using `typeahead` directive referring this [example](https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv), but my data is coming from `json` file (`webservice` call).

I am getting an error on this line

```
<input ng-model="selected" ng-change="getdata()" typeahead="dataAddress for dataAddress addressData" | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:2/>
```

`Angular` code:

```
$scope.getdata =function(){
$http.get("address.json&id=2&q="+$scope.selected).then(function (res) {
    $scope.addressData = res.data.response.topSuggestions;
    console.log($scope.addressData)
});
};
```

`json` content:

```
{"response":{"sequenceNumber":2,"topSuggestions":[{"address":{"detectedLanguage":"en","isComplete":true,"searchBarString":"aaaaaasdasdd","string":"aaaaaasdasdd","municipalityName":"aaa","postalCode":"1007"}}]}}
```

I want to select `address` and `string`.

I called the service for each single character the user hit by adding that, search.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!